# Error in Hierarchical Bayesian estimation of the Drift-Diffusion Model in Python

Tags: model, pycharm, bayesian

For the purpose of model selection, I was running the following model:

```
m_group = hddm.HDDM(data, depends_on={'v':['coher','sat','group'],
                                      'a': ['coher','sat','group'],
                                      't':['coher','sat','group']})
m_group.find_starting_values()
m_group.sample(2000, burn=20, dbname='traces.db', db='pickle')
```

Then i run the following command for testing significance between conditions:

```
print "P(5 >15)=",
(v_5.trace() > v_15.trace()).mean()
```

I got the following error message:

> P(5 >15)=Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line
>   2883, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "", line 2, in 
>       (v_5.trace() > v_15.trace()).mean() AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'trace'

By the way, when i'm running a simpler model as following, the mentioned command is working well:

```
m_group = hddm.HDDM(data, depends_on={'v':['coher']})
m_group.find_starting_values()
m_group.sample(2000, burn=20, dbname='traces.db', db='pickle')
```

Would appreciate any help.
Thanks, 
Rotem